# Section-wise numbering in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, page-numbers

I have a document divided into the following sections:

- Cover Page
- TOC
- Main Content
- Appendices

  - Appendix A
  - Appendix B
  - Appendix C

I have inserted section breaks to have four sections in the document.

Now, in the Appendix section, I wish to have the numbering in the following format in the footer: 'Appendix A-1... Appendix A-2.... Appendix A-*n*',  'Appendix B-1... Appendix B-*n*'.

I have been able to get the numbering restarted once I get to the Appendix section. But how do I insert the title of the appendix, that is, Appendix A or B, before the number?

Can you please help me how I can achieve this functionality in MS Word?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the sections split and the page numbering working correctly, you should just be able to write `Appendix` before the page number on `Page 1` of each Appendix footer and it should replicate the writing on each page of the section but still allow the page numbers to be incremental (that is count upwards).

Hope this helps.

For automated, it's a little bit trickier and requires the use of field codes (and also requires the use of Microsoft Word Styles).

So if you are only focusing on the Appendix sections, start on the first page of `Appendix A` and edit the footer. If you already have a footer set highlight it, `right-click` and select `Edit Field...`.

In `Field names` select `StyleRef` and then to the right select the `Style` that you have used for your Appendix headings, in my case it was `Heading 1` as seen in the picture below:

[image]

This should give you the name of your heading (which will hopefully be Appendix A). Then just `copy` that and `paste` it right next to it which will give you something that looks like below:

[image]

These two are completely different entities so you can put `spaces`, `hypens`, `random writing`, etc between them and it will all be replicated. Highlight all of the writing, `right-click` and select `Toggle Field Codes`. Highlight all of the writing in the the second lot of `curly brackets {}` and just replace it with `PAGE`. Then add your `spaces` and `hypens` to get the look you are after as below (then toggle the field codes back to get your final product):

[image]

[image]

This should update all of your Appendix A footers to match this look with the page number being continuous. Finally go to your Appendix B page 1 footer and select `Link to Previous` confirming when it asks you to remove existing data:

[image]

This should give you an identical looking footer starting with Appendix B - 1. Do the same thing for Appendix C, Appendix D, etc and hopefully it does exactly what you are after.

Comment: i want it to be automated. i would like it to pick up the title of the Appendix, Appendix A or B, without me having to manually insert it.

Comment: Edited my original post for an automated process

Comment: I got it to work Brad; i applied a new style for appendices and used the StyleRef field code to achieve the desired result. Thank you for the direction and guidance. I feel your approach is more elegant, but as i was working my way through this i found another way: (1)So, the point is to first, create a new list and then apply the formatting to one of the existing chapter heading styles, say Heading 2.
(2)You need to apply section breaks between each appendices
(3)Then, in the format page number dialog, you check the option – Include Chapter Number.